# Terminate jquery fade effect on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fade

I'm trying to build this effect where divs fade in and out continuously. Where it gets tricky is that I need those fadeIn and fadeOut effects to stop on hover.

Right now, this code that I have doesn't stop all fading quickly. What I need is an override? Is that even possible?

```
function animate() {
    $("#bill-items-one").fadeIn(3000);

    one = setInterval(function(){
        $("#bill-items-one").fadeOut(3000);
        $("#bill-items-one").fadeIn(3000);
    }, 6000)

    two = setInterval(function(){
        $("#bill-items-two").fadeIn(3000);
        $("#bill-items-two").fadeOut(3500);
    }, 6500)

    three = setInterval(function(){
        $("#bill-items-three").fadeIn(2000);
        $("#bill-items-three").fadeOut(4000);
    }, 6000)

    four = setInterval(function(){
        $("#bill-items-four").fadeIn(3500);
        $("#bill-items-four").fadeOut(3000);
    }, 6500)
}

animate();

$(".bill-area").hover(
    function(){
        clearInterval(one);
        clearInterval(two);
        clearInterval(three);
        clearInterval(four);
        $(".bill-item").fadeOut("fast");
    },
    function(){
        animate();
    }
);
```

See also this link: http://jsfiddle.net/bKKE6/

Comment: Have you looked at http://api.jquery.com/stop/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

```
$(".bill-item").stop().fadeOut("fast");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [`stop`[docs]](http://api.jquery.com/stop/):

```
$(".bill-area").hover(
    function(){
        $(".bill-item").stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
    },
    function(){
        animate();
    }
);
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bKKE6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `.stop()` to stop animations.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/